# AS3---TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Flash is giving me this error after I click a button to go to another frame. After I get the error, some buttons do not go to its destination and instead it just does nothing.

The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at wmhssports_fla::MainTimeline/frame39()
```

Here is the code for frame 39:

```
stop();

winter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick1);
function buttonClick1(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay(39);
};

spring_btn_boys.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick10);
function buttonClick10(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay(114);
};

fall_btn_boys.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick11);
function buttonClick11(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndPlay(135);
};
```

Comment: Are `winter_btn`, `spring_btn`, and `fall_btn` defined in frame 39?
Try to `trace(fall_btn);` and see what you get.

Comment: I'll take a look at the file. Upload it to a service like mediafire.com, and send the link via the contact form on my site (check my profile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at your flash movie/application and the following is the solution to your problem:

[image: .alt text]

The above image is a screenshot of the timeline of your flash movie/application. It's at frame 39 that you recieve the error "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at wmhssports_fla::MainTimeline/frame39()". You recieve this because at that point the instance, `spring_btn_girls`, of your `spring_btn` button is null. To solve this give the instance of your `spring_btn` button the instance name "spring_btn_girls" on frame 34.

Answer (score 0):

One of the buttons you're linking to either doesn't exist (typo of instance name?) or isn't on the frame you're coding on.

As John said, try `trace(winter_btn, spring_btn, fall_btn);`. The one that returns `null` is the one that you want to rectify.

Comment: well I already know which ones they are,  The spring and the fall buttons don't work. Winter works for some reason. The instance names are correctly spelled and all three of them appear on frame 39

Comment: @user571620 - It's been a while since I've done timeline flash, but I vaguely remember that if the layer the movieclip resides on has ended prior to the call, it will be deleted/garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set it up so it'll tell you what line of code is throwing the error. Here's a blog post I wrote on the subject: http://mykola.bilokonsky.net/2010/08/get-line-numbers-on-runtime-errors-in-flash/

Good luck!